# Apache wont run as www-data, runs as root

Tags: apache-2.2

How can i get Apache to run as `www-data`?

Apache wont run as `www-data`. `ps aux` prints:

```
root     24525  0.0  0.3  69652  8932 ?        Ss   12:22   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     24533  0.0  0.1  69652  4260 ?        S    12:22   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     24534  0.0  0.1  69652  4248 ?        S    12:22   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     24535  0.0  0.1  69652  4248 ?        S    12:22   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     24536  0.0  0.1  69652  4248 ?        S    12:22   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     24537  0.0  0.1  69652  4248 ?        S    12:22   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

I expect the first process to be run as root since i need to bind to `81` but the rest i want running as `www-data`.

My config `envvars` file contains

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

And my `apache2.conf` contains:

```
# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User www-data
Group www-data
```

(I hard coded these as a desperate attempt)

I have even tried to run `/usr/sbin/apache2 -c "User www-data"` with no luck.

nginx runs as `www-data`, so i assume that the users exists and works.

The error.log shows only:

```
[Wed Jun 18 14:07:53 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze19 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: What distribution do you use? What is the error message what you get ?

Comment: Debian Squeeze. I dont get any error messages from what i can see.

Comment: Is running as root even if you start it with: service apache2 start?

Comment: Well, did you compile it from source or did you install it via apt-get install apache2 ? By default it will run as www-data on Squeeze.

Comment: I got it from apt. And yes, it runs at root even then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will probably never know what caused this, but a apt-purge of apache2 and all it's dependencies, then a reinstall through apt-get made it work again.

Thanks to all of you who tried to help me.